# Display facebook page posts on website with custom design

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-permissions

I'm trying to display the posts from a facebook page on the respective website, the thing is I cant use the plugin Page Plugin or Embedded Posts because I want to have the posts automatically updated (every time the client posts on facebook, the new post should appear automatically on the website) and also I want to provide a custom design to the posts (so that it matches the website design).

I can fetch the info I need by using the following endpoint

https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/{pageID}/feed?fields=full_picture%2Cmessage%2Cpermalink_url%7Blink%7D,created_time&limit=2&access_token={access_token}

Now, in order to use this endpoint, the faceboook graph told me that I needed the "Page Public Content Access" permission, which facebook kept rejecting, saying that it wasnt the right permission. So, after another search I found that, by having "publish_pages
" and "manage_pages" I could also achieve the same results. But now, facebook is requesting me to go through the business verification which seems way to much work just to show a couple on posts on a website.

I'm I doing something wrong? is there a easier way?

Comment: If you only want to show posts on your site, then you need `manage_pages` only, `publish_pages` would only be required if you want to publish _to_ Facebook from within your system. And yes, you will need to get your app reviewed. _“which seems way to much work just to show a couple on posts on a website”_ - well your “less work” options would be the plugins … if you don’t like the look & feel of those, then you need to do the extra work.

Comment: The extra work I was referring to is the business verification. It seems to me that is not required to do all this steps to just show a post 
 1º Connect your app to a business
 2º Provide business details
 3º Send contract to business signatory
4º Contract signed.

Anyway, i going to try using just the manage_pages, maybe that way I dont need to do the business verification. Thanks !